# Remix Solidity compiler is giving error (Expected token Semicolon got 'Returns')

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler

When I debug a similar contract in [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/):

```
function ConstructorFunction(uint _inputOne, uint _inputTwo){
    callsAnotherFunction('string') returns (bool success);
}
```

I am returned this error:

> contract.sol:2:36: Error: Expected token Semicolon got 'Returns'
>
> callsAotherRunction('string') returns (bool success);
>
> ```
>                           ^
> ```

(note regarding formatting: '^' appears beneath the 'r' in 'returns')

This seems to occur everytime I include a returns after a function. What is the appropriate syntax?

Comment: returns inside {} is out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ConstructorFunction(uint _inputOne, uint _inputTwo)
  public
  returns (bool success)
{
    callAnotherFunction('string');
    return true;
}
```

With summarized explanation:

```
// describe the function i/o and visibility
// input - types and optional variable name assigments 
function ConstructorFunction(uint _inputOne, uint _inputTwo)
  // visibility
  public
  // output - returned type(s) and optional labels
  returns (bool success)
// define the function
{
    // do something
    callAnotherFunction('string');
    // return args with types that match expected interface described above
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.